# createSession with NotesFactory

Tags: java, xpages

In a JAVA Bean I need access to a NotesSession so that I can create a NotesDirectory and open a Database by RepID (do it all the time in SSJS. my code containes this

```
import lotus.domino.Base;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.View;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.View;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntry;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntryCollection;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.Directory;
import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;
.....

Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();
db = s.getCurrentDatabase();
```

it fails on the db = s.CurrentDatabase(). I have added some code and checked the object "s" and it is null based on my search the NotesFactory creates a new NotesSession which I'm assuming should not be null. If I remove reference to "s" I can make the code run without error, but can't do what I want to. 
I know that I can get the current db by doing

```
Database db = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
```

but that does not solve the problem of opening a target database by replica ID which I have to do a little later in my code.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? If it is a `NullPointerException` it is because `NotesFacotry.createsSession()` is returning `null`

Comment: It does throw a NullPointerException when calling db = s.getCurrentDatabase(). "s" is null but it should not be. The question is why does it not create a Session? This should be pretty simple, I would think, and I have found lots of examples of this sort of code where Session s = NotesFactory.createSession() is used.

Comment: NotesFactory requires an initThread() before it works and is designed for standalone Java, not XPages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the session to be in the context of the current user. So just use:

```
  ExtlibUtil.getCurrentSession();
```

Check some [articles from Declan](http://www.qtzar.com/getting-to-the-java-roots-of-xpages-part-3/) to learn more about Java in XPages.

Reading the source of ExlibUtil is quite enlightening too. It is just a wrapper around the variable resolver.

Comment: Checked ot the series by Declan and wish I had read it earlier. In one regard there is almost to much documentation and yet not enough. Wish there was a book like the Mastering XPages but Mastering XPages and Java. The NotesFactory.createSessionlooked like the natural way to open a session - obviously not - So much of what is available on the internet assumes a level of understanding that is beyond many Newbies (like myself - been developing N/D applications for almost 20 years, but XPages about a year and JAVA not so much). But I'm getting there and thanks for the pointers.

Comment: You might want to look for a classic: Developing Notes with Java by Bob Balaban. For the ones coming from Notes it is a good intro into Java. Afaik he posted it online. Then read Head First Java from O'Reilly. Thereafter Thinking in Java. The 3rd edition is a free PDF. Don't start with it, it would scare you